# AutoCad with .net : how to capture Alt key event while select item by click

Tags: .net, events, keyboard, autocad

I am developing  a plugin for AutoCad.

In a command loop , user will select some text objects by clicking them or By window.

for example : `text1` , `text2` , `text3` , `text4` , `text5` , `text6` , `text7`

1. User type command: multiselect
2. user click on `text1`
3. user press on ALT key on the keyboard
4. user click on `text2`
5. user click on `text3`
6. user select `text4` and `text5` by Window
7. user release ALT key
8. user select `text7`
9. Press ENTER to end multiSelect command

Through this command I want to generate a list like this :

```
[
  {string : "text1" , groupId : 1},
  {string : "text2" , groupId : 2},
  {string : "text3" , groupId : 2},
  {string : "text4" , groupId : 2},
  {string : "text5" , groupId : 2},
  {string : "text6" , groupId : 3},
  {string : "text7" , groupId : 3},
]
```

Could someone show me some hints on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

So what does the ALT key do if you can select `text7` without pressing it?...oh, wait, I see, it determines `groupId`. I think that UX is confusing, you're better off doing something more clear selecting each group with ENTER between them, tell the user they're selecting the next group and how to move on, and the ENTER after nothing is selected to finish the input sequence. Have a think about what is intuitive for the user.

You could use a [selection filter](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-125398A5-184C-4114-9212-A2FF28FC1F1D) to only get Text with a loop of  `Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.GetSelection(SelectionFilter)` and build your array from the `SelectionSet`s you get from that.

Read the AutoCAD tag wiki for forums you can search for more info.